# How to add a copy of each line in a txt (containing two parts separated by a particular symbol) with the order of the two parts inverted?

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I have txt with a number of lines (x@y). Each file has two parts (x, y) separated by a particular symbol (@). How would a python script that reads each line in a txt and adds a new line under each existing line, where the order of the two parts (x@y) is inverted (y@x).

What I'm trying to do presented as input/output:

INPUT:

```
x1@y1
x2@y2
x3@y3
```

OUTPUT:

```
x1@y1
y1@x1
x2@y2
y2@x2
x3@y3
y3@x3
```

How can this be done with python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumes the name of your file is bar.txt, and that you want to write it back to bar.txt. It also does no error checking nor cares about memory usage.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfile = open("bar.txt", "rb")
    lines = myfile.readlines()
    myfile.close()

    myfile = open("bar.txt", "wb")
    for l in lines:
        ls = l.strip()
        myfile.write(ls + "\n")
        lsplit = ls.split("@")
        myfile.write(lsplit[1] + "@" + lsplit[0] + "\n")

    myfile.close()
```

Comment: For noobs (like me) who want to use this: This script was the first that worked for me. *After* I made sure the path to the .py and .txt file had no spaces. (I think that was it.)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
infilename = 'in.dat'
outfilename = 'out.dat'
sep = '@'

with open(infilename) as infile, open(outfilename,'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        split = line.strip().partition(sep)
        outfile.write(line)
        outfile.write(''.join(reversed(split)) + '\n')
```

and then

```
~/coding$ cat in.dat 
x1@y1
x2@y2
x3@y3
~/coding$ python inverter.py 
~/coding$ cat out.dat 
x1@y1
y1@x1
x2@y2
y2@x2
x3@y3
y3@x3
```

Answer (score 0):

There are cleaner ways to do this, but you could use something like:

```
f = open('my_file.txt', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

outfile = open('my_file2.txt', 'w')

# write each line, followed by flipped line
for line in lines:
    outfile.write('%s\n' % line)
    parts = line.split('@')
    outfile.write('%s@%s\n' % [parts[1], parts[0]])

outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `open` and `read` function to read your [file](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html) and than use this function,

```
>>> st = "x1@y1"
>>> def myfunc(string):
...       mylist = re.split(r'(@)',string)
...       mylist.reverse()
...       print "".join(mylist), string
...
>>> myfunc(st)
y1@x1 x1@y1
```

and than use `write` to write the strings into your new file.

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap(delimiter="@", input="input.txt", ouput="output.txt"):
    with open(input, "r") as input_file, open(ouput, "w") as output_file:
            for line in input_file:
                line = line.strip()
                output_line = delimiter.join(reversed(line.split(delimiter)))
                output_file.write(line+"\n")
                output_file.write(output_line+"\n")

swap()
```

Answer (score 0):

Riffing on @DSM:

```
with open(infilename) as infile, open(outfilename, 'w') as outfile:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in infile]
    outfile.write("\n".join("%s\n%s%s%s" (line, y, sep, x)
        for line in lines
        for x, y in line.split(sep)) + "\n")
```

`lines` could also be a generator statement instead of a list comprehension:

```
lines = (line.rstrip() for line in infile)
```

---

Later: I did not realize until now that OP wanted the original line followed by the reversed line. Adjusted accordingly.